# GridsearchCV tuning KerasClassifier with callbacks error: ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples

Tags: callback, scikit-learn, keras, deep-learning, grid-search

Using `sklearn.GridSearchCV` to fine tune the hyperparameters of model in Keras. Also, I add `callbacks` into it.

Input Format: (1500, 3, 10, 10)

Output Format: (1500,)

Grid search code:

```python
def Grid_Search_Training(model):

    # parameters grid
    epochs = [300]
    activations = ['relu', 'tanh']
    L2_lambda = [0.01, 0.001, 0.0001]
    batches = [16, 32, 64, 128]
    param_grid = dict(activation=activations, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batches, L2_lambda=L2_lambda)
    grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, scoring='accuracy', cv=5)

    return grid

def run(grid_search = True): 

    model = Model()
    plot_model(model, to_file='Model_plot.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)

    # save layer names into a set, to visualize all layers' output in tensorboard
    embeddings_all_layer_names = set(layer.name for layer in model.layers if layer.name.startswith('tower_'))

    # train and save the model weights
    Model_weights_path = 'Model_weights.h5'

    checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(Model_weights_path, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

    reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2, patience=5, min_lr=0.0000001)

    tensorboard_log_dir = 'ModelLogs/{}'.format(time.time())
    tensorboard  = TensorBoard(log_dir = tensorboard_log_dir, histogram_freq = 1, 
                                write_graph=True, write_images=True, embeddings_freq=1,
                                embeddings_layer_names=embeddings_all_layer_names, embeddings_metadata=None)

    callbacks_list = [checkpointer, reduce_lr, tensorboard]
    fit_params = dict(callbacks=callbacks_list)


    if grid_search:

        t0 = time.time()
        print incepModel().summary()
        model = KerasClassifier(build_fn = model, verbose=1)

        grid = Grid_Search_Training(model)
        print 'Start Training the model......'
        grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
        print("Best acc Score: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))

        t1 = time.time()
        t = t1-t0

        print 'The GirdSearch on CNN took %.2f mins.' %(round(t/60., 2))
        means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
        stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
        params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
        for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
            print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))

    else:
        history = model.fit(X_train, to_categorical(y_train), epochs=100, batch_size=64, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=callbacks_list)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = read_split(data)

run(grid_search=True)
```

The error is :

```python
    grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train, fit_params)
  File "/Users/jd/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 615, in fit
    X, y, groups = indexable(X, y, groups)
  File "/Users/jd/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 229, in indexable
    check_consistent_length(*result)
  File "/Users/jd/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 204, in check_consistent_length
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1500, 1500, 1]
```

The code works well without `callbacks`, i.e. No `fit_params` in `grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train, fit_params)`. There is no error.

**What causes such kind of error?**

Comment: Try `grid.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)`

Comment: @VivekKumar. I just tried it, the error became `File "/Users/jd/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1272, in _build raise ValueError("No variables to save")`

Comment: The new one is a tensorflow error, make sure you are using the callbacks correctly. First try an example without gridsearch. GridSearch problem is solved.

Comment: @VivekKumar. While not doing gridsearch, the model runs well. While doing it, I found it is not the problem of `callbacks`. `grid.fit(X_train, y_train` raised error `TypeError: can't pickle NotImplementedType objects`. Same as the one in this link: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11157

Comment: Ok.So did you try the solutions mentioned on that page? Thanks for notifying me about this. I was talking about the problem you originally posted when I said that gridSearch problem is solved.